# loadAsync in JSZip is not waiting to get completed

Tags: javascript, zip, jszip

I am using JSZip library on browser UI and having a "content" which I am passing as body for creating a zip.

```js
var contentDiff: async function(content){
      zip = await JSZip.loadAsync(content, {base64: true});
      return zip.files;
},//other functions below this
```

Now, I am new but this "zip.files" comes as undefined in a later method call, even after calling await.
Kindly suggest what is missing in this js.

I tried different variations of async await and promises, but all in vain.

Comment: If you log `zip` before returning, do you get some value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this worked for me. Calling the contentDiff function and using then function. The only hard thing was to rewrite lots of old js lines of code into different function calls and then chaining it under then statement and subsequently in other async then statements. Guess, there is no way, async await will pause/hold code flow in real time when used in synchronous JS processes.

```
contentDiff(content).then(function (body){
   //do processing on body here.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you also use an `await` when calling the `contentDiff`-function?

And/or maybe there is an error which is missed. The documentation of `loadAsync` mentions:

> The promise can fail if the loaded data is not valid zip data or if it
> uses unsupported features (multi volume, password protected, etc).

Try someting like:

```
var contentDiff: async function(content){
  zip = await JSZip.loadAsync(content, {base64: true})
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
  return zip.files;
}
```

A slightly shorter version:

```
var contentDiff: async function(content){
  return JSZip.loadAsync(content, {base64: true})
    .then((zip) => zip.files)
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
}

await contentDiff(data);
```

Comment: The problem is it doesn't wait for contentDiff to complete and moves forward.